# Mac OS Catalina : Can't execute ruby from PHP

Tags: php, ruby, macos, macos-catalina

I've updated my Mac to Catalina version.
Since this new release of Mac OS, i'm not able to execute ruby from PHP anymore.

I can't find anything of internet.

This is how I call ruby from PHP

```
$cmd = "ruby duplicate_ios.rb '$xcode_version' '$xcodeproj_path' '$bundle_id' '$display_name' '$target_source' '$target_destination' '$iosTeamID'";
$outputDuplicateTarget = system($cmd);
```

When I execute from terminal, it works.
But not when it's from PHP.
And before Catalina release, it worked.

**EDIT**
in ruby script

```
require "xcodeproj"
```

=> seem to be the origin of the crash (only from php script)

Comment: `But not when it's from PHP.` <- define where PHP is?

Comment: PHP is executed from MAMP Apache2. PHP is in /usr/bin/php folder

Comment: If you try with full path in your php script  "/usr/bin/ruby /my/path/duplicate_ios.rb" it works?

Comment: Thanks, but do not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION :**

PHP was run in MAMP, which using a special ruby version.

Use "php -S 192.168.xx.xx:8888" instead of MAMP fixed the problem !

Answer (score 1):

Apple has removed Ruby and other scripting languages from their OS, [see deprecations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_catalina_10_15_release_notes#3318257)

You probably will want to use a ruby version manager such as RVM.  For install instructions see https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: I've installed ruby : it works from the terminal, but not from the php script

Answer (score 1):

For maintaining a current, up-to-date environment on macOS you have several options:

- [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) which is a minimally invasive version manager you can install with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).
- [`rvm`](https://rvm.io) which is more cross-platform, but which embeds more deeply in your shell environment.

Both of these allow you to install different versions of Ruby simultaneously and switch between them automatically with a `.ruby-version` file in your project's directory. This makes working with older code-bases quite effortless.

They also allow you to install Ruby gems without having to `sudo` anything as the gems are installed for one user only.

**WARNING**: When calling `system()` in PHP it's extremely important to properly escape any and all data arguments. Use [`escapeshellcmd`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) to handle the escaping. If you fail to do this you run the risk of command errors due to conflicting quotes, or worse, as a user could potentially hijack your system by running arbitrary shell commands.